# Set custom attribute value from Enum in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, attributes

I have one custom attribute like below,

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class SetValForAll : Attribute
    {
        public string Limit { get; set; }

        public SetValForAll(string limit)
        {
            Limit = limit;
        }
    }
```

While using this attribute(SetValForAll) I want to pass the value of **Limit** using one Enum but it is showing error 'An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type'

My Enum is like below,

```
        public enum LimitEnum
        {
            max,
            min
        }
```

The below piece of code is throwing error in the attribute line.

```
[SetValForAll(LimitEnum.max.ToString())]
public class UsingTheAttributeHere
{
}
```

How I can take value from LimitEnum while using **SetValForAll** attribute, rather than passing hardcoded string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `nameof` expression that will get you the `enum` as a string constant:

```
[SetValForAll(nameof(LimitEnum.max))]
```

([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof).)

Comment: that's a good idea to pass the name as a constant string.

Comment: Thank you @stenehr. It works. I have mark your answer as Accepted

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't pass non-constant strings in attribute values. Why don't you use your `enum` type instead of `string` for your property? You can use `LimitEnum` to pass in the constructor.

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class SetValForAll : Attribute
    {
    public LimitEnum Limit { get; set; }

    public SetValForAll(LimitEnum limit)
    {
        Limit = limit;
    }
    }
```

and use it like this :

```
[SetValForAll(LimitEnum.max)]
```

Comment: for your answer. This could be the better option. Thank you for your suggestion